# ¿Cómo centrar un Label con Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Con una imagen creo que es mas claro, deseo centrar el texto de un label en un form, como verán en la imagen tiene un margen en la parte inferior de donde tengo mi figura y que también esta con su puntero. Creo que es lo que le impide que el texto se centro de una manera horizontal con respecto al otro control, como lo puedo solucionar por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo:

```
<div class="row">
 
    <div class="col-sm-12">

<form asp-action="Create">

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="AnticipoId" class="control-label col-sm-4 text-right"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input asp-for="AnticipoId" class="form-control" />
            </div>



            <span asp-validation-for="AnticipoId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Les agradezco por la valiosa ayuda.

Roberto

Comment: Tu código está incompleto, te podría ayudar mejor si me mandas todo el formulario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poner el label centrado respecto al input en un form usando Bootstrap es bastante sencillo, en el sitio de Bootstrap cuentas con numerosos ejemplos, te dejo link a la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/).

Como no has proporcionado todo el formulario me limitaré a dejarte un ejemplo de como puedes hacer para que el label esté al lado del input utilizando la clase `col` como viene recomendado en el link de la documentación. Yo utilizaré para mi ejemplo `col-auto` pero tu puedes utilizar un `col` con el numero que necesites, ej: `col-2`.

Aquí tienes el código de ejemplo:

```
<div class="container m-3">
    <form class="row g-3">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-auto col-form-label">Contraseña</label>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword">
        </div><!--//col-->
    </form><!--//form-row-->
</div><!--//container-->
```

Así se verá en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado Ariel, muy bueno el ejemplo, pero creo que mi problema pasa por eliminar primero ese espacio que tiene el label en la parte de abajo, para que pueda jalar hacia abajo mi texto. por lo pronto aun no lo he conseguido

Comment: Muchas gracias., me hicieron notar que no hice lo que Ud. me sugería. Gracias Ariel

Comment: Siempre se puede ayudar de algún modo ;)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar aplicando este estilo al label

```
.tu-clase-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: En este caso no es necesario añadir otro CSS, se puede hacer todo con Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es simplemente centrar el label lo puedes hacer con boostrap mediante
`d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center`, lo que hace `justify-content-center` es centrar de manera horizontal y `align-items-center` centra de manera vertical.
El codigo seria el siguiente

```
<label style="background-color: silver" asp-for="AnticipoId" class="control-label col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">AnticipoId</label>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con `m-0` para que quede con el mismo tamaño del input de la derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<label style="background-color: silver" asp-for="AnticipoId" class="control-label col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center m-0">AnticipoId</label>
```

Por ultimo si quieres que el label quede al lado del input entonces agregale `col-auto`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label style="background-color:silver;" asp-for="AnticipoId" class="col-auto d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ml-3 p-2">AnticipoId</label>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <input asp-for="AnticipoId" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="AnticipoId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```